# How can Log4j be used with Spark cluster in a distributed environment?

Tags: java, logging, apache-spark

In our project, we are going to use spark cluster with 100 nodes. For logging purpose, we are using log4j but not sure if it will be supported in a distributed environment. In this scenario,

1. Where will be the logs written? Would there be any centralised location?
2. Would multiple nodes be able to write in a single log file?
3. It would be helpful if you could provide any documentation for the same

Comment: In distributed systems, you usually have some service responsible for collecting logs from nodes and sending them to a centralized location. [*LogStash*](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash), and generally the entire ELK stack seems to be popular in those areas.

Comment: Also if you are using YARN and the YARN history server is enabled all Spark logs including executor's log will be aggregated to HDFS and will be available via `yarn logs -applicaitonId <id>`. And yes - log4j is fine.

Comment: To answer where the logs will be found depends on the cluster manager you will be using. Will it be a standalone cluster or YARN cluster?

Comment: @sameeksha are u able to figure it out ?..i got stuck up doing the same .If you resolved .Please help me do the same